# How to turn off warning for no xml comment in VS 2005

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, settings

At some point in time I turned on a setting in Visual Studio 2005 that produces a warning when methods/classes don't have an xml comment associated with them.  I would like to turn  this off, but can't seem to find the setting again.  Anyone know where this is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right-click your project and goto Properties.

Select the Build tab on the left.

Under Supress Warnings enter... 1591,1592,1573,1571,1570,1572.

Though I don't recommend this because the whole point of generating documentation is to have it documented.  If you don't like the warnings you can de-select the warning option in the errors list pane of VS.

Comment: @Chad Moran: +1, or add those to a list to promote to errors ;D

Comment: Sorry, -1. To me XML Comments are to hard to maintain to be used in normal code (public symbols that are just used by myself will never get in a chm, or, if they will, they will never be read there). For most situation (I mean everything but API development), XML Comments should be avoided.

Comment: 1587 and 1574 can be added. Invalid cref and invalid XmlDoc position respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a .NET project, the setting is on Project properties > Build tab. Near the bottom, in the Output section, there is a check box labeled "XML documentation file".

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is turning off XML documentation generation. This can be done on under Project properties / Compile / Generate XML documentation file.

Comment: You can supress the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can either turn off the documentation generation for the whole project in the project properties (you'll need to do that for each build configuration), you can disable the warnings on the whole project in the project properties, or you can disable the warning on individual code blocks using the ["#pragma warning" directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys(VS.80).aspx).